# Facebook unity SDK implementation with other plugin

Tags: android, facebook, plugins, unity-game-engine

Is there now a way to use the facebook plugin unity at the same time as other plugins (prime31 for example)?

I use multiple plugin other than facebook (push, in app purchase), and when I import the facebook plugin, it is impossible to compile because of resource sharing. I found a lot of topics on this issue, but I have not been able to solve my problem.

Here is an example of compile-time errors:

```
stderr[
res\values\attrs.xml:20: error: Attribute "show_pictures" has already been defined
res\values\attrs.xml:21: error: Attribute "extra_fields" has already been defined
res\values\attrs.xml:22: error: Attribute "show_title_bar" has already been defined
res\values\attrs.xml:23: error: Attribute "title_text" has already been defined
res\values\attrs.xml:24: error: Attribute "done_button_text" has already been defined
res\values\attrs.xml:25: error: Attribute "title_bar_background" has already been defined
res\values\attrs.xml:26: error: Attribute "done_button_background" has already been defined
res\values\attrs.xml:29: error: Attribute "multi_select" has already been defined
res\values\attrs.xml:32: error: Attribute "radius_in_meters" has already been defined
res\values\attrs.xml:33: error: Attribute "results_limit" has already been defined
res\values\attrs.xml:34: error: Attribute "search_text" has already been defined
res\values\attrs.xml:35: error: Attribute "show_search_box" has already been defined
res\values\attrs.xml:38: error: Attribute "confirm_logout" has already been defined
res\values\attrs.xml:39: error: Attribute "fetch_user_info" has already been defined
res\values\attrs.xml:40: error: Attribute "login_text" has already been defined
res\values\attrs.xml:41: error: Attribute "logout_text" has already been defined
res\values\attrs.xml:44: error: Attribute "preset_size" has already been defined
res\values\attrs.xml:50: error: Attribute "is_cropped" has already been defined
]
```

If anyone has a solution let me know!

thank you,

Answer (score 1):

This happened to me when I had multiple attrs.xml files in my plugins folder, probably because of using the Facebook Unity plugin along with the Prime31 unity plugin.  I deleted one of the attrs.xml files (which I found using the Unity search function) and then this error went away.

Answer (score 0):

You can use multiple plugins from prime31 at the same time, just make sure that you have only one copy of **P31RestKit.dll**.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response. My problem is not how to use multiple prime31 plugins, which I already doing, but how to use the Facebook SDK for unity with prime31 plugins :)